# How to disable json output from specific ansible commands?

Tags: ansible

Some ansible commands produce json output that's barely readable for humans. It distracts people when they need to check if playbook executed correctly and causes confusion.

Example commands are `shell` and `replace` - they generate a lot of useless noise. How can I prevent this? Simple **ok | changed | failed** is enough. I don't need the whole JSON.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Use `no_log: true` on those tasks where you want to suppress all further output.

```
- shell: whatever
  no_log: true
```

I believe the only mention of this feature is within the [FAQ](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/faq.html#how-do-i-keep-secret-data-in-my-playbook).

Example playbook:

```
- hosts:
  - localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    test_list:
      - a
      - b
      - c
    
  tasks:
    - name: Test with output
      shell: echo "{{ item }}"
      with_items: test_list
  
    - name: Test w/o output
      shell: echo "{{ item }}"
      no_log: true
      with_items: test_list
```

Example output:

```
TASK: [Test with output] ****************************************************** 
changed: [localhost] => (item=a)
changed: [localhost] => (item=b)
changed: [localhost] => (item=c)

TASK: [Test w/o output] ******************************************************* 
changed: [localhost]
changed: [localhost]
changed: [localhost]
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I'm using `ansible-playbook 2.0.0` and `no_log: True` has no effect on `shell`, `copy` and `replace` commands. The hint might be that I use `with_items` for all of these commands.

Comment: Well, 2.0.0 is an alpha release. I added an example above and it works with Ansible 1.9.2

Comment: It seems that v 2.0.0-0.3.beta1 behaves in a more human friendly manner  when it comes to message output.

Comment: Tried this with `set_fact ... with_dict` in Ansible 2.6.1 and instead of the JSON I get "=> (item=None)" output for each key/value pair.

Comment: Output is sightly different in Ansible 2.8. It now shows as follows `ok: [localhost] => {"censored": "the output has been hidden due to the fact that 'no_log: true' was specified for this result", "changed": false}`

Comment: Good answer, but this is true when the following properties are not overridden in ansible.cfg: `verbosity`, `callback_whitelist`. For instance, with `verbosity = 1` or `callback_whitelist = timer, profile_tasks` output will produce censored messages and timestamps (the last is used for measuring purposes).

Answer (score 0):

You can use -o - one line output with ansible command (not with ansible-playbook):

```
ansible -o -m shell -a 'command' target
```

It will put hostname, command return code and command output in same line:

```
hostname1 | CHANGED | rc=0 | (stdout) command output
hostname2 | CHANGED | rc=0 | (stdout) command output
hostname3 | CHANGED | rc=0 | (stdout) command output
```

Comment: The question specifically mentions that the OP is working with a playbook.