# Conditionals in ansible without "FAILED" json output

Tags: ansible

I want to run a command based on whether or not a certain RPM is installed.  I have a series of tasks that look something like the following:

```
- name: This is the test for the RPM
  command: rpm -q some-rpm
  register: rpm_is_installed
  ignore_errors: True
- name: Command to run if the RPM is installed
  command: some_command_to_run
  when: rpm_is_installed is succeeded
```

Functionally, this works.  However, if the test fails (i.e. the RPM is not installed), I get a nasty JSON printout describing the failure when it does the "rpm -q some-rpm".  This gets ignored so ansible continues and everything effectively runs as it's supposed to but I would like to suppress that error output so I don't see that error message every time I run these tasks.

I did find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32475881/how-to-disable-json-output-from-specific-ansible-commands) which suggests adding the "no_log: True" in the test task.  This does not suppress the output in my version of ansible, but changes the output to:

> FAILED! => {"censored": "the output has been hidden due to the fact that 'no_log: true' was specified for this result"}

Is there a way to suppress the output of a failed command?

- Ansible: 2.4.2.0
- OS: RHEL 7.7

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of suppressing the error logs but one thing that you can do is to use `failed_when`.

`no_log: true` --> This will censor the output.

`ignore_errors: true` --> This will ignore the error and continue the play.

`failed_when: false` --> This will not let task fail.

Playbook would look like this :

```
- name: This is the test for the RPM
  command: rpm -q some-rpm
  register: rpm_is_installed
  failed_when: false
  no_log: true
```

Apart from `ignore_errors`, here is the `failed_when` option where you can define exactly what makes the task fail. We should not let the task fail in the first place. In this case, task will never fail.

Output without failed_when :

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "censored": "the output has been hidden due to the fact that 'no_log: true' was specified for this result", 
    "changed": true
}
```

Output with failed_when :

```
changed: [localhost] => {
    "censored": "the output has been hidden due to the fact that 'no_log: true' was specified for this result", 
    "changed": true
}
```

These are the only combination you can use to ignore, censor and not let the task fail.

Comment: Actually, try adding `log: true` under `provisioner:`